# Dell XPS 17 laptop shuts down unexpectedly when running on battery power

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown

I have a Dell XPS 17 (L702X) and the problem is that whenever I use the laptop on battery without it connected to AC it will only work for a random amount of time before it will suddenly shut down. This has been happening for a number of months now. The battery is new as I bought it a week ago—along with a new hard drives—and it still does this.

On AC power I can use the laptop for as long as I wish without it shutting down unexpectedly.
The shutdown is hasted by how much I use the laptop for example it can be a hour or so if just left alone with just the desktop on screen. But if i play a game it will be maybe about 15 minutes.

Comment: Are you sure the new battery is really new, and also that it's not faulty?

Comment: Sounds like a faulty battery. [BatteryInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html) can provide insight into what's going on—the logging feature can come in really handy.

Comment: yeah bought from duracell direct.

not sure how to check if the battery is faulty used the batteryinfoview tool should i leave this up until it shuts down again and see if the log says anything?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, this seems like a bad battery, though new.

In Windows 7 or 8, open a CMD prompt *as Administrator* and enter

**powercfg -energy**

In a minute you'll have a report that includes battery condition, e.g.

*Battery:Battery Information* ...

**Design Capacity     48600**

**Last Full Charge    46580**

The difference between design and current (no pun intended) capacity gives an idea of the battery condition. [See How to check your laptop battery health in Windows 7](http://www.helpwithwindows.com/Windows7/Check-your-laptop-battery-health-in-Windows-7.html) for more detail (this works on Windows 8.1, as well).

Also go to *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings*, *Change advanced power settings* and examine * Battery* settings to check if you're laptop is set to shut down when there is still considerable charge left.

Comment: Battery:Battery Information
Battery ID 33920PANASONICDell
Manufacturer PANASONIC
Serial Number 33920
Chemistry LION
Long Term 1
Sealed 0
Design Capacity 86580
Last Full Charge 86580

the design and current capacity are exactly the same. is there something else i should look for?  and thanks for the help

Comment: There seems to be a few threads on the web dealing with Dell battery charging issues. You could try the advice at http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-vista/dell-laptop-battery-plugged-in-not-charging/8236.html: shut and unplug laptop; remove battery; plug back in and run on AC adapter for a while, then shut down and reinstall battery.  **Check the power plan, though, to see if it;'s shutting down while there's still charge in the battery.**